# How can I display TimeSpan in correct format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How can I do that?

That is the code

```
<%# (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("user_lastlogin"))) %>
```

it shows it this way

```
17:55:43.2322234
```

instead of

```
17:55:43
```

Comment: The subtraction of two DateTime is TimeSpan.but you have written a time!

Comment: @mohsen so there is nothing I can do D:?

Comment: For 17:55:43.2322234 you must use ToLongTimeString method and for 17:55:43 use ToShortTimeString of your DateTime instance

Comment: What you have written in your code is : " How long time is user had login ?"

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want

Comment: Use `.ToString("hh\":\"mm\":\"ss")`

Comment: @mohsen yes, that is what I'm looking for. Calculated time since last time user logged in

Comment: @Widi Thanks, that worked. Hmm, I tried to do that but without those \" symbols and got errors before, lesson learnt :o

Comment: @Harugawa The `"`s escape the `:` as they would be considered a formatting symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use ToString("format") method of TimeSpan

```
<%# (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("user_lastlogin"))).ToString("hh':'mm':'ss") %>
```

More information :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx